# fontenc.sty broken line 115

Tags: siunitx, font-encodings, tlmgr, texlive-2019

I've updated texlive this morning (2020-02-25 - 8.40 CET) and my documents, that compiled without trouble yesterday, report this error today:

```latex
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty:115: Undefined co
ntrol sequence.
l.115 \xdef\@fontenc@load@list{\@fontenc@load@list

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

It might be related to siunitx package (perhaps the command `\micro`), xelatex,  fontenc, inputenc.

Right now, I don't have an MWE yet - hope that someone could help without it. If not, I'll edit tomorrow with an MWE.

Comment: My file ´fontenc.sty´ did not change during the update, so it must be another package causing trouble.

Comment: Your format hasn't been updated correctly. Check with `kpsewhich --engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt` if you have a local format that overshadows the system format.

Comment: This results in `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt`: I believe there is something else wrong with web2c on my system, as texlife previously reported missing files (in the texmf directory in my home directory). Hmm?!?

Comment: I'm compiling with xelatex. Using `kpsewhich --engine=xelatex xelatex.fmt` results in no output. Is this ok?

Comment: `--engine=xetex` not xelatex.

Comment: If the format is also in texmf-var, try to recreate it with `fmtutil-sys --all`.

Comment: OK with `--engine=xetex`, I get: `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xelatex.fmt`

Comment: `fmtutil-sys --all` gives `zsh: command not found: fmtutil-sys` - even though the tab-auto-complete can find the command

Comment: `tlmgr install texlive-scripts`

Comment: I have the same problem as OP, but on MikTeX ... Not sure how to resolve it without tlmgr ...

Comment: Same situation, in MikTeX, was for me resolved running "Refresh font database" from MikTeX Console menu.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I ran `fmtutil-sys --all` but when trying to compile I still get `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty:115: Undefined co
ntrol sequence.`. When executing `kpsewhich --engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt` I get `/home/jon63587/.texlive2019/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt`. I installed some extra fonts in `/home/jon63587/texmf/tex/latex`, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: delete the format in `/home/jon63587/.texlive2019/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt`, it is shadowing the system format.

Comment: thank you! I just saw your comment after finding the same solution and writing an answer for it. Should I keep my answer for better visibility or should I delete it as it is basically what you already suggested earlier in your comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fmtutil-sys` (since a re-organisation last year) is part of `texlive-scripts` so

```
tlmgr install texlive-scripts
```

should make it available, and can then be used to rebuild the formats from the updated sources.

Comment: Confirmed: yes it does.

Comment: how can one do this if texlive has been installed via apt-get and therefore tlmgr cannot be used?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 1**
Thanks to the (simultaneous) posts from @David Carlisle and @Ulrike Fischer the command `tlmgr install texlive-scripts` filled `usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive` with the relevant scripts and now it looks like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x   22 root  staff     704 25 Feb 19:15 .
drwxr-xr-x  155 root  staff    4960 28 Jan 00:02 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root  staff   13587 27 Jan 23:11 NEWS
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    2143 27 Jan 23:11 README
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     929 20 Apr  2015 fmtutil-sys.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     926 19 Aug  2019 fmtutil-user.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel   50589  7 Jan 00:55 fmtutil.pl
drwxr-xr-x    2 root  wheel      64 17 Dec 09:05 lua
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  staff    8209 29 Dec 20:18 mktexlsr
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel   16696 30 Jul  2015 mktexlsr.pl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    4007 29 Dec 20:18 mktexmf
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    9895 30 Jan 23:18 mktexpk
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    5913 30 Jan 23:18 mktextfm
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     901 25 Apr  2013 rungs.tlu
-rw-r--r--    1 root  staff     177  4 Jul  2019 tl-errmess.vbs
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  staff  339072 27 Jan 19:20 tlmgr.pl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  staff   91549 11 Mar  2019 tlmgrgui.pl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  staff    2272 10 Dec 07:20 uninstall-win32.pl
-rw-r--r--    1 root  staff     408 13 Mar  2019 uninstq.vbs
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     925 20 Apr  2015 updmap-sys.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     922 19 Aug  2019 updmap-user.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel   87469  7 Jun  2019 updmap.pl
```

**END EDIT 1**

So far I patched the original problem with great advice from the comments from @Ulrike Fischer:

I found out, that the directory `usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive` no longer contained the files shell script `fmtutil-sys.sh` and the perl scripts `fmtutil.pl` and `mktexlsr.pl`. I copied those three over from my 2017 distribution, executed `fmtutil-sys -all` and ended up with this final result:

```
Transcript written on utf8mex.log.
fmtutil [INFO]: /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/utf8mex.fmt installed.
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `mf-nowin -ini   -jobname=mf -progname=mf -translate-file=cp227.tcx mf.ini </dev/null' return status 1
fmtutil [ERROR]: return error due to options --strict
fmtutil [INFO]: Disabled formats: 5
fmtutil [INFO]: Successfully rebuilt formats: 38
fmtutil [INFO]: Failed to build: 1 (mf-nowin/mf)
fmtutil [INFO]: Total formats: 44
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 1
```

My original question above is at least workaround-patched, as my document compiles again. Therefore I dare to post this as an answer hoping, that it might be useful for someone else. Even it's not perfect.

In between I also tried to "Reinstall Tex Live Manager" from the GUI (in menu "Actions"), which did not help.

Note there are multiple other scripts missing in my 2019 installation compared to the 2017 installation - which might or might not kick in for someone else.

Here's an ls -la from the texlive directory in the 2017 distribution:

```
drwxr-xr-x   34 root  staff    1088 24 Maj  2017 .
drwxr-xr-x  136 root  staff    4352 24 Maj  2017 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root  staff    7140 19 Maj  2017 NEWS
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    3482 25 Nov  2016 allcm.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     903 25 Nov  2016 allneeded.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    1098 25 Nov  2016 dvi2fax.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    3081 25 Nov  2016 dvired.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    2728 25 Nov  2016 e2pall.pl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     929 25 Nov  2016 fmtutil-sys.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     876 21 Apr  2017 fmtutil-user.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel   48066  4 Maj  2017 fmtutil.pl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     552 25 Nov  2016 fontinst.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    3457 25 Nov  2016 kpsetool.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    1441 25 Nov  2016 kpsewhere.sh
drwxr-xr-x    3 root  wheel      96 24 Maj  2017 lua
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel   16696 25 Nov  2016 mktexlsr.pl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     229 25 Nov  2016 ps2frag.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    1446 25 Nov  2016 pslatex.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    2583 25 Nov  2016 rubibtex.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    1791 25 Nov  2016 rumakeindex.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     901 25 Nov  2016 rungs.tlu
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    1121 25 Nov  2016 test-tlpdb.tlu
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel   20865 25 Nov  2016 texconf.tlu
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel   13262 25 Nov  2016 texconfig-dialog.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    1038 25 Nov  2016 texconfig-sys.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel   43330 24 Apr  2017 texconfig.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel   10274 25 Nov  2016 texlinks.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  staff  299941 19 Maj  2017 tlmgr.pl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  staff   91501 17 Maj  2017 tlmgrgui.pl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  staff    2907 25 Nov  2016 uninstall-win32.pl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     925 25 Nov  2016 updmap-sys.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel     873 21 Apr  2017 updmap-user.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel   86718 14 Maj  2017 updmap.pl
drwxr-xr-x    3 root  staff      96 24 Maj  2017 var
```

and one from the 2019 distribution (after I've copied over the thee above montioned files):

```
drwxr-xr-x   14 root    staff     448 25 Feb 18:20 .
drwxr-xr-x  155 root    staff    4960 28 Jan 00:02 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root    staff   13587 27 Jan 23:11 NEWS
-rw-r--r--    1 root    staff    1603 29 Dec 20:18 README
-rwxr-xr-x    1 aknott  staff     929 25 Nov  2016 fmtutil-sys.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 aknott  staff   48066  4 Maj  2017 fmtutil.pl
drwxr-xr-x    2 root    wheel      64 17 Dec 09:05 lua
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root    staff    8209 29 Dec 20:18 mktexlsr
-rwxr-xr-x    1 aknott  staff   16696 25 Nov  2016 mktexlsr.pl
-rw-r--r--    1 root    staff     177  4 Jul  2019 tl-errmess.vbs
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root    staff  339072 27 Jan 19:20 tlmgr.pl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root    staff   91549 11 Mar  2019 tlmgrgui.pl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root    staff    2272 10 Dec 07:20 uninstall-win32.pl
-rw-r--r--    1 root    staff     408 13 Mar  2019 uninstq.vbs
```

Comment: I think you are missing texlive-scripts, try to install it.

Comment: Yes. That works. As David also posted nearly simultaneously with you.

Comment: David and me spoke in the chat about it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and suspect that it was due to some fonts I manually installed on my latex system. None of the previous answers worked for me and eventually I managed to fix it by deleting the ~/.texlive2019 folder and then running

```
sudo mktexlsr
updmap-sys --enable Map pfr.map
updmap-sys --enable Map sitdings.map
```

EDIT: I just saw @UlrikeFischers comment below OP's question. She said that the format in `~/.texlive2019/...` was shadowing my system format and deleting it would solve the problem.