# Fontenc last 2020 update issues

Tags: font-encodings

Upon updating latex (the last update for the 2019 version), I receive the following error:

The issue is in line 115 of the "fontenc.sty", it says "undefined control sequence", this issue appeared in all my files, it killed all my work !!:

```
\xdef\@fontenc@load@list{\@fontenc@load@list
```

The file used to run normally before the update, I am using lualatex + biblatex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 


\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Simplified Arabic}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlistdepth{9}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,4]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,5]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,6]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,7]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,8]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,9]{label=$\bullet$}
\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{9}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt} 

\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\ListProperties(
                Style1*=\textbullet\ \ ,
                Style2*=\begin{normalfont}\begin{bfseries}\textendash\end{bfseries}\end{normalfont} \ \ ,
                Style3*=\textasteriskcentered\ \ ,
                Style4*=\textperiodcentered\ \ ,
                Style5*=\textbullet\ \ ,
                Style6*=\begin{normalfont}\begin{bfseries}\textendash\end{bfseries}\end{normalfont}\ \ ,
                Style7*=\textasteriskcentered\ \ ,
                Style8*=\textperiodcentered\ \ ,
                Hide1=1,
                Hide2=2,
                Hide3=3,
                Hide4=4,
                Hide5=5,
                Hide6=6,
                Hide7=7,
                Hide8=8 )
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu,multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{?}[1]{!{\vrule width #1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}




\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 


\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\begin{center}
\caption{التفخيم والترقيقXIV باللغة العربية}
\label{tab:التفخيم والترقيق}
\begin{tabular}{@{}m{0cm}@{}?{1mm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}c?{1mm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{6.5cm}?{1mm}}
\rowcolor{white}
\cmidrule[2.5pt]{3-6}
\rowcolor{white} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
\cellcolor{white}
 &

 &
\textbf{التعريف}
 &
\textbf{الحروف}
 & 
\textbf{أمثلة}
 & 
\textbf{ملاحظات}  
\\
\cmidrule[2pt]{2-6}
\rowcolor{gray!25}   
\rule{0cm}{5.5cm} 
\cellcolor{white}
 &
\textbf{التفخيم}
 &
تسمين صوت الحرف عند النطق به
 &
"خُـصّ ضَـغْـطٍ قِـظْ" (تسمى حروف الاستعلاء)
 & 
 خــالـديـن
الــصـادقـين
الــضـالـين
 &  
\cellcolor{white}
\multirow[c]{2}{=}[2.5cm]
{
\textbf{وهنالك أحرف الأصل فيها الترقيق ولكنها تفخم في الحالات التالية:}
\begin{itemize}
\item
الألف المدية :
\begin{itemize}
\item
 تتبع ما قبلها تفخيما وترقيقا.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
\item
حرف اللام في لفظ الجلالة(الله):
\begin{itemize}
\item
إذا سبق لفظ الجلالة فتح أو ضم
\item
عند البدء ب لفظ الجلالة.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
\item
حرف الراء:
\begin{itemize}
\item
عندما يكون مفتوحا أو مضموما.
\item
عندما يكون ساكنا III وقبله فتح أو ضم.
\item
عندما يأتي ساكنا III بعد كسر وبعده في الكلمة نفسها حرف تفخيم.
\item
عندما يقع بعد كسر عارض.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}
\\
  \cmidrule[2pt]{2-5} 
  \rule{0cm}{5.5cm}
  \cellcolor{white}
 &
    \textbf{الترقيق}
 &
تنحيف صوت الحرف عند النطق به
 &
بـاقي أحرف اللغة العربية (تسمى حروف الاستفال)
 & 
الــتــائـبون
الــعابدون
الــحامدون
 &  

\\
\cmidrule[2pt]{2-6}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The initial value of `\@fontenc@load@list` is built into the LaTeX format. It seems the LaTeX format wasn't rebuild after your update

Comment: Do you have any suggestions/solutions?

Comment: What version of LaTeX do you have? The current one is `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5` (you find that at the top of the log file). Also, what distribution do you use? TeXLive? MiKTeX?

Comment: I am using texlive, regarding the version I am using: This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX)  (format=lualatex 2020.3.27)  27 MAR 2020 22:03
 restricted system commands enabled

Comment: What does the line starting with "LaTeX2e" say?

Comment: LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5 Lua module

Comment: If I remove the `\babelfont[arabic]` line your example document compiles. Can you confirm that?

Comment: But I do need the arabic !!!

Comment: @Silva Yes, I know, but if removing that line solves the problem we narrow down the issue. I asked that because I don't have that font in my system, and without it the example compiles

Comment: Yes, it does work!

Comment: @Silva I tried with Fira GO (I couldn't find a `Simplified Arabic` font) and the document compiled correctly. Can you please upload the log (of the run that errors) somewhere, so I can take a look?

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik, Thank you, the solution provided by David Charlise resolved the issue, THX https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529930/fontenc-sty-broken-line-115